# YII Application does not work after changed to VPS Centos

Tags: .htaccess, yii

The YII application was working before in shared hosting.

This is the YII application

http://www.jualrumahjakarta.com/iklan

These links are not working

```
www.jualrumahjakarta.com/iklan/site/login
www.jualrumahjakarta.com/iklan/user/register
```

---

htaccess in "iklan" folder

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

---

in main.php

```
'urlManager'=>array(
'urlFormat'=>'path',
'showScriptName'=>false,
 'caseSensitive'=>false,        
),
```

I have the same application for another website in shared hosting and it is working.

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide Yii log? I think problem can be because of using "/iklan" path as site root. But Yii is configured to use simple "/".

Comment: @andres Where I can see the log file ?
I have the same module with the same path in shared hosting, and it is working. Before this, it also worked in shared hosting.
You can see the working version in www.jualsewatanah.com/iklan